# POEdit: Can't update translations from Source Code

Tags: razor, poedit

I am using POEdit for translations in a web application.

However, when I start POEdit I can't find any sources when I run 'Catalog > Update from Sources'. I only have .CSHTML-Files where the texts need to be translated.

What I've already tried:

1. Set the source path in Catalog > Properties and the charset to
   'UTF-8'.
2. Added additional keyword ("[[[w+]]]") for matching words in my files (the words to translate always have the following form: [[[wordToTranslate]]]
3. Added a cshtml-extractor (In File > Settings > Extractor). When I did this, the following error message appeared: "warning: unterminated string constant". Warning: ')' found where '}' was expected.
4. Browsing the web without finding any clue of how to include cshtml-files.

Any hints are appreciated.
Any solutions are MUCH appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Added additional keyword ("[[[w+]]]") for matching words in my files

I don’t know why you assume the keyword values are regexes of all things; they are not. The GNU gettext manual makes it clear what “keyword” is in the gettext context: *name of the function* used to call gettext with translatable string literals as the argument.

> Added a cshtml-extractor

You get errors coming from this, it would be reasonable to assume that’s the problem. Because you gloss over this crucial step and don’t reveal the details of *how* you configured it, it’s impossible to give you a concrete answer (not without a crystal ball, anyway).

So I can only make an educated guess: if you didn’t actually add a proper extractor that understands the syntax of the template language you use, and used some gross hack like using the Python parser, then that’s the cause of your errors, together with the use of keyword value that can’t possibly be valid.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up creating a batch-file which extracts the translations and add them to a .PO-File. Problem solved!

Comment: @FabianBigler it would have been nice to share that script in a new answer and mark it as accepted.